# Why the PHP $_FILES variable doesn't exist if I don't choose any files and call the File API while submitting the form in IE?

Tags: javascript, php

I have tried the code like below:

**HTML:** (index.html)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script>
function foo(){
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<form action="s.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" onsubmit="foo();">
    <input type="file" name="f" id="f" />
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

**PHP:** (s.php)

```
<?php
if(isset($_FILES['f'])){
    var_dump($_FILES['f']);
}else{
    echo "Variable \$_FILES['f'] does not exist.";
}
?>
```

If I don't choose any files and submit the form, it works fine and the variable `$_FILES['f']` exists in IE11, also the Chrome.

The `var_dump` of `$_FILES['f']` looks like this:

```
array(5) {
  ["name"]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["type"]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["tmp_name"]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["error"]=>
  int(4)
  ["size"]=>
  int(0)
}
```

But if I change the function `foo()` into the code like below:

```
function foo(){
    console.log(document.getElementById("f").files);
}
```

I still don't choose any files and submit the form, the PHP will echo `Variable $_FILES['f'] does not exist.` in IE. (but in Chrome, the variable `$_FILES['f']` still exists and the `var_dump` result is same as above)

Why the variable `$_FILES['f']` does not exist if I am trying to call the File API while submitting the form in IE?

What's the problem about it? Is it a bug of IE?

Comment: What's in `$_FILES['f']` when you don't choose any files?

Comment: It'll show like this: `array(5) { ["name"]=> string(0) "" ["type"]=> string(0) "" ["tmp_name"]=> string(0) "" ["error"]=> int(4) ["size"]=> int(0) }`. Even though i didn't choose any files, but the variable `$_FILES['f']` still exists...

Comment: https://gist.github.com/ebidel/2410898